# Facing problems compiling python with Nuitka

Tags: python, c++, nuitka

I'm having problems compiling a simple python program to exe using nuitka

test1.py

`print "Hello World!"`

nuitka command

`nuitka.bat test1.py`

Error :

`C:\Python\Scripts>nuitka.bat test1.py g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-static-libstdc++' scons: *** [test1.exe] Error 1`

i looked for help on google but i couldn't find anything regarding the error

this is my g++ version

`g++ (tdm-1) 4.7.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

according to the manpage i only need version 4.4+ so i guess the version is not an issue .

i'd appreciate any help

Comment: Isn't there anyone who can help me ..

Comment: Are you using MinGW?

Comment: @JohnBargman yes i'm using MiniGW . i contacted the creator of nuitka he said it was an issue with my g++ version "tdm-1" . but i've since given up on nuitka and cython , actually i was thinking maybe they could compile python to a smaller exe . but i guess that's not possible . so i'm sticking to the traditional and noob friendly packing methods e.x cx_Freeze and py2exe